# Trying to correct Vegan package error "'dist' cannot be all zero (all points are identical)" for one observation

Tags: r, vegan, multi-dimensional-scaling

I am conducting non-metric multidimensional scaling (nmds) with the vegan package in RStudio for a case study (i.e., n=1). However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Error in monoMDS(dist, y = cmdscale(dist, k = k), k = k, maxit = maxit,  : 
  'dist' cannot be all zero (all points are identical)
```

I know that other researchers have conducted case studies using nmds, but I am using a different survey tool - the interpersonal reactivity index (IRI; Davis 1980, 1983), which measures self-perceived dispositional empathy. I want to see the distances between the four subscales (F, EC, PD, POV).

Any help is resolving this error is appreciated. Thank you!

I used the following code, but once I ran the nmds, I received the error.

```
data_JA_select <- data_JA %>%
   dplyr::select(IRI_EC_1, IRI_EC_2,IRI_EC_3,IRI_EC_4,IRI_EC_5,IRI_EC_6,IRI_EC_7, IRI_POV_1, IRI_POV_2, IRI_POV_3, IRI_POV_4, IRI_POV_5, IRI_POV_6, IRI_POV_7, IRI_F_1,  IRI_F_2,  IRI_F_3, IRI_F_4, IRI_F_5, IRI_F_6, IRI_F_7, IRI_PD_1, IRI_PD_2, IRI_PD_3, IRI_PD_4, IRI_PD_5, IRI_PD_6, IRI_PD_7)

data_JA_nmds <- metaMDS(data_JA_select, k = 2, distance= "euclidean", trymax = 100)
```

Please note: data_JA is my cleaned data that I can use for other analyses, and is not a problem.

Below is the data_JA*_*select table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZ3S.png)

Comment: I am not sure that you are correctly describing your problem as the description sounds so crazy. If you have one point (n=1), you may just add a condition (if statement) that sets coordinates 0 on all dimensions for that one point with stress 0.

Comment: Indeed, that does sounds crazy. I have 28 points, just one observation (i.e., one person; n=1). The 28 points represent 28 items from a scale with four subscales (7 items/scale).

Comment: NMDS nees inter-point distances. If you have 28 points, you need 28 * 27 / 2 distances. The default is that points (or observations) are rows. Arrange them so. However, with just one variable (person, observations being items), your distance measure may be degenerate.

Comment: Thank you. From what I understand I cannot conduct the analysis with one person.